# Does android have a slider view?

Tags: android, view, slider

Hi i was wondering if android has view that responds to user slides.

If you want to know exactly what i mean there is one in the galaxy tab for unlocking the phone and muting/activating sound on the bottom of the screen.

Seems like the iPhone slide to unlock feature.

Thanks in advance I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GestureOverlayView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html) might help you.

See also:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGestures/article.html

Comment: Here is a sample project that connects a `GestureOverlayView` to a `ViewFlipper`, for allowing horizontal swipes to flip between children: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper

Comment: This answer now leads to a 404. Go to this link instead: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html

Answer (score 0):

All the views can respond to "user slides". In Android, this is a gesture called fling or swipe. You can see [this tutorial for a sample implementation](http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/16/how-to-implement-swipe-action-in-android/).

Basically:

- implement onFling of SimpleOnGestureListener in your own class
- call your gesture listener from the onTouch method of the view